# Rails strong params ignoring named param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, strong-parameters

In config/routes.rb I have the following code

```
  resources :orders, param: :no do
    resources :order_items, param: :line_item do
      collection do
        get :price
      end
    end
  end
```

If I post to `/orders/6061734/order_items`, via json. Then I get the following params:

```
{"line_item"=>3, "stock_no"=>265062, "order_no"=>"6061734", "order_item"=>{"line_item"=>3, "stock_no"=>265062}}
```

For parameter whitelisting I have

```
  def order_item_params
    params.require(:order_item).permit(:order_no, :line_item, ...)
  end
```

I submitted `line_item` and `stock_no` via json parameters and `order_no` via the url. The `order_item` param was created by [ActionController::ParamsWrapper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html). The documentation states

> On Active Record models with no :include or :exclude option set, it
>   will only wrap the parameters returned by the class method
>   attribute_names.

There is no include or exclude option set on the order_item model, so I am confused as to why order_no is not "wrapped" in the order_item params. Is is because it is part of the url and not part of the json params? I checked OrderItem.attribute_names in the rails console. order_no, line_item and many other attributes are returned.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think my response requires a full answer, but I don't have enough reputation points to just comment.

Let's take a look at your strong parameter implementation.

```rb
params.require(:order_item).permit(:order_no, :line_item, ...)
```

Using the `#require` specifies that every attribute you are permitting exist in the `:order_item` sub-hash. From the parameters you posted, it looks like `:order_no` lives outside of that sub-hash. In order to get at the `:order_no` parameter, the following could be used.

```rb
params.permit(:order_no)
```